# uploadify returns a value after uploading

Tags: php, mysql, uploadify

What I'm trying to do and achieve are:

1. I want to upload an image during the registration of a user. Let's say, I have a form that accepts input as name and input file upload(uploadify button) and a save button.

uploadify.php

```
$targetFolder = 'uploads';
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
jQuery('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'swf'      : plug+'/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.swf',
         'uploader' : plug + '/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.php'
        // Put your options here
    });
```

How will I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 events which you can use for this:

- http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploaderror/
- http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadsuccess/
- http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadcomplete/

I would suggest you use `onuploaderror` and change the return code of your php script to match so it only handles errors.